# Как завершить определённый цикл в php?

Tags: php, циклы

В подцикле нужно завершить верхний цикл. В js видел такое - cycle_name: for() { continue cycle_name; }

```js
for($v = 0; $v < count($arr); $v++) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
      if('NORTH' == $arr[$v] && 'SOUTH' == $arr1[$i]) {
        continue cycle_name;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Прервать выполнение двух циклов: `break 2;`

Answer (score 0):

```php
    for ($v = 0; $v < count($arr); $v++) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
        if ('NORTH' == $arr[$v] && 'SOUTH' == $arr1[$i]) {
          $v = count($arr);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если надо проверить есть ли в одном массиве один элемент и в другом массиве другой элемент, то не надо никаких вложенных циклов:

```
if (in_array('NORTH', $arr) && in_array('SOUTH', $arr1)) {
    echo 'Нужное условие найдено!';
}
```